# Некорректно отрабатывает счётчик

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема? Не округляются десятичные(

```js
$('.le-quantity div').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elem = $(this).parent().parent().find('input.counter');
  var currentQty = elem.val();
  var cur = Math.round(currentQty * 100) / 100;


  if ($(this).hasClass('minus') && cur > 0) {
    elem.val(cur - 0.1);
    elem.trigger("change");
  } else {
    if ($(this).hasClass('plus')) {
      elem.val(cur + 0.1);
      elem.trigger("change");

    }
  }
});
```

```css
.le-quantity {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input-number__add {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="le-quantity"> 
 <div class="input-number product__quantity plusMinus">
 <input id="product_price"  class="input-number__input form-control form-control-lg counter" type="text" name="count" step="0.01" min="1" maxlength="3" value="1">
<div class="input-box">
  <div class="input-number__add plus">+</div>
  <div class="input-number__add minus">-</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так

```js
$('.le-quantity div').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elem = $(this).parent().parent().find('input.counter');
  var currentQty = +elem.val()*10;
  var cur = currentQty;


  if ($(this).hasClass('minus') && cur > 0) {
    elem.val((cur - 1)/10);
    elem.trigger("change");
  } else {
    if ($(this).hasClass('plus')) {
      elem.val((cur + 1)/10);
      elem.trigger("change");

    }
  }
});
```

```css
.le-quantity {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input-number__add {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="le-quantity"> 
 <div class="input-number product__quantity plusMinus">
 <input id="product_price"  class="input-number__input form-control form-control-lg counter" type="text" name="count" step="0.01" min="1" maxlength="3" value="1">
<div class="input-box">
  <div class="input-number__add plus">+</div>
  <div class="input-number__add minus">-</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```